# Kusto ingestion error "BadRequest_EmptyArchive: Empty zip archive"

Tags: azure-data-explorer, data-ingestion

I have a bunch of .csv files in Azure blob storage, and an ingestion rule to pull them into Kusto (Azure Data Explorer).  This used to work, but I've been getting a lot of ingestion failures lately.  ".show ingestion failures" gives me:

```
Details FailureKind OperationKind   ErrorCode   ShouldRetry IngestionProperties IngestionSourcePath
BadRequest_EmptyArchive: Empty zip archive  Permanent   DataIngestPull  BadRequest_EmptyArchive 0   "[Format=Csv/mandatory, IngestionMapping=[{""column"":""CrashSource"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""0""},{""column"":""CrashType"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""1""},{""column"":""ReportId"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""2""},{""column"":""DeviceId"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""3""},{""column"":""DeviceSerialNumber"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""4""},{""column"":""DumpFilePath"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""5""},{""column"":""FailureXmlPath"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""6""},{""column"":""PROCESS_NAME"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""7""},{""column"":""BUILD_VERSION_STRING"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""8""},{""column"":""DUMP_TYPE"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""9""},{""column"":""PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""10""},{""column"":""IMAGE_NAME"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""11""},{""column"":""FAILURE_BUCKET_ID"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""12""},{""column"":""OS_VERSION"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""13""},{""column"":""TARGET_TIME"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""14""},{""column"":""FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""15""},{""column"":""FAILURE_ID_HASH"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""16""},{""column"":""FAILURE_ID_REPORT_LINK"",""datatype"":""string"",""Ordinal"":""17""}], ValidationPolicy=[Options=ValidateCsvInputConstantColumns, Implications=BestEffort], Tags=[ToStringEmpty], IngestIfNotExists=[ToStringEmpty], ZipPattern=[null]]"  https://crashanalysisresults.blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net/datacontainer/Telemetry.37c92f1a-a951-4047-b839-e685bd11758f.zip.crashanalysis.csv
```

My CSV files are *not* zipped in blob storage.  Do I need to do something with ZipPattern to say so?
Here's what this CSV contains (many strings simplified):

```
CrashSource,CrashType,ReportId,DeviceId,DeviceSerialNumber,DumpFilePath,FailureXmlPath,PROCESS_NAME,BUILD_VERSION_STRING,DUMP_TYPE,PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS,IMAGE_NAME,FAILURE_BUCKET_ID,OS_VERSION,TARGET_TIME,FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING,FAILURE_ID_HASH,FAILURE_ID_REPORT_LINK
"source","type","reportid","deviceid","","dumpfilepath","failurexmlpath","process","version","1","problem class","image","bucket","version","2020-07-27T22:36:44.000Z","hash string","{b27ad816-2cb5-c004-d164-516c7a32dcef}","link"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often happens.  I seem to have found my own answer just by asking.  While reviewing my question, I realized the string ".zip" is in the middle of my CSV file name.  (Telemetry.37c92f1a-a951-4047-b839-e685bd11758f.zip.crashanalysis.csv)  That made me wonder if Kusto is treating it differently based on that.  I tested by taking the exact same file, renaming it "Telemetry.37c92f1a-a951-4047-b839-e685bd11758f.crashanalysis.csv", and uploading it.  This was successfully ingested.

<forehead smack> I guess I will rename my files to get past this, but this sounds like a Kusto ingestion bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this, Sue.

Yes, Kusto automatically attempts to check files with ".zip" in them. We'll check why this is "tripping" if the string is in the middle of the file name instead of just its end.